# What is the purpose of metaclass methods being defined on classes but not instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A method defined on a metaclass is accessible by classes that use the metaclass. However, the method will not be accessible on the instances of these classes.

My first guess was that metaclass methods would not be accessible on either classes or instances.

My second guess was that metaclass methods would be accessible on both classes and instances.

I find it surprising that metaclass methods are instead accessible on classes, but not on instances.

What is the purpose of this behavior? Is there any case where I can use this to an advantage? If there is no intended purpose, how does the implementation work such that this is the resulting behavior?

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        mcs.handle_foo(dct)
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)
    
    @classmethod
    def handle_foo(mcs, dct):
        """
        The sole purpose of this method is to encapsulate some logic
        instead of writing code directly in __new__,
        and also that subclasses of the metaclass can override this
        """
        dct['foo'] = 1

class Meta2(Meta):
    @classmethod
    def handle_foo(mcs, dct):
        """Example of Metaclass' subclass overriding"""
        dct['foo'] = 10000


class A(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

class B(metaclass=Meta2):
    pass

assert A.foo == 1
assert B.foo == 10000

assert hasattr(A, 'handle_foo')
assert hasattr(B, 'handle_foo')
# What is the purpose or reason of this method being accessible on A and B?
# If there is no purpose, what about the implementation explains why it is accessible here?

instance = A()


assert not hasattr(instance, 'handle_foo')
# Why is this method not accessible on the instance, when it is on the class?
# What is the purpose or reason for this method not being accessible on the instance?
```

**What is the purpose of this behavior? What use case is this behavior intended to support? I am interested in a direct quote from the documentation, if one exists.**

If there is no purpose, and this is simply a byproduct of the implementation, why does the implementation result in this behavior? I.e., how are metaclasses implemented such that the methods defined on the metaclass are also <strike>defined</strike> accessible on classes that use the metaclass, but not the instantiated objects of these classes?

---

There is only one practical implication of this that I have found is the following: Pycharm will include these metaclass functions in the code completion box when you start typing `A.` (i.e., the class). I don't want users of my framework to see this. One way to mitigate this as by renaming these methods as private methods (e.g. `_handle_foo`), but still I would rather these methods not show up in code completion at all. Using a dunder naming convention (`__`) won't work, as subclasses of the metaclass will not be able to override the methods.

---

(I've edited this post extensively due to the thoughtful feedback from Miyagi and Serge, in order to make it more clear as to why I am defining methods on the metaclass in the first place: simply in order to encapsulate some behavior instead of putting all the code in `__new__`, and to allow those methods to be overridden by subclasses of the metaclass)

Comment: I doubt there's a "direct quote from the documentation" to be presented. It's just how classes and instances work. Methods defined on a class aren't also defined on the instances, and likewise methods defined on a metaclass (a class' class) aren't also defined on the class (the mataclass' instance) – they are *accessible* through the instances as *bound* methods. You are confusing how classes and instances work, there's nothing special about metaclasses.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi When I say "defined" I mean "accessible" in your terminology. Methods defined on a class are accessible on an instance. Methods defined on a metaclass are accessible on a class, but are not accessible on the instance. What is the purpose of this design? If there is no purpose, how does the implementation result in this?

Comment: Whatever you call it, the problem is that you equate "defined/accessible" on the metaclass and class. That's not the case between classes and instances either.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi If have have a misunderstanding, then would you be able to explain why a method defined on a metaclass is accessible on a class but not on an instance of that class? I would have thought that methods defined on the metaclass should not be accessible in the class at all. And if they were accessible on the class, I would expect them to also be accessible on the instance of the class. I find it is odd that both of these are incorrect.

Comment: I don't think I can do so to your standard – there is barely any "why" officially documented for these metatopics. I can *cite* the relevant parts that document *how* this works, but there is rationale for it – I can only speculate on that.

Comment: "I would have thought that methods defined on the metaclass should not be accessible in the class at all." That would make them pointless. Methods are defined on the class and called via the instance. It's the same when the instance itself is a class (as an instance of a metaclass).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  if one is not available in the official documentations, I would be satisfied with an explanation of the implementation. I would also appreciate citations of the relevant parts that document how this works, if convenient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242671/discussion-between-matthew-moisen-and-mistermiyagi).

Comment: It sounds like the real source of the confusion here is `classmethod`, more than metaclasses. The root confusion is just the fact that classmethods are available on instances, and the metaclass issue is just a complication on top of that.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica both regular methods and classmethods defined in the metaclass are not available on instances, but they are available on classes. The root of my confusion is that I don't understand why methods defined on the metaclass are available on classes, but not instances. I would have thought it would not be accessible on either, or accessible on both, but not one or the other.

Comment: Aren't you confusing instances of the metaclass with instances of a class whose definition is using the metaclass?

Comment: @Timus I'm confused in general :) but I don't think I'm confusing this particular point. Instances of the metaclass (i.e., the class) can access methods defined on the metaclass. But instances of the class cannot access these same methods. Why? What purpose/use case does this serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first look at this in a non-meta situation: We define a function inside a class and access it via the instance.

```py
>>> class Foo:
...     def bar(self): ...
...
>>> Foo.bar
<function __main__.Foo.bar(self)>
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar
<bound method Foo.bar of <__main__.Foo object at 0x10dc75790>>
```

Of note is that the two "attributes" are not the same kind: The class' attribute is the very thing we put into it, but the instance's "attribute" is a dynamically created thing.

Likewise, methods defined on a metaclass are not *inherited* by the class, they are (dynamically) *bound* to its classes.

```py
>>> Meta.meta_method  # direct access to "class" attribute
<function __main__.Meta.meta_method(cls)>
>>> Foo.meta_method   # instance access to "class" attribute
 <bound method Meta.meta_method of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
```

This is the exact same mechanism – because a class is "just" a metaclass' instance.

---

It should be obvious at this point that the attributes defined on the metaclass and dynamically bound to the class are not the same thing, and there is no reason for them to behave the same. Whether lookup of attributes on an instance picks up metaclass-methods from their dynamic form on the class, directly from the metaclass or not at all is a judgement call.

[Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) defines that default lookup only takes into account the instance and the instance's type. The instance's type's type is explicitly excluded.

> #### [Invoking Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors)
>
> […]
> The default behavior for attribute access is to get, set, or delete the attribute from an object’s dictionary. For instance, `a.x` has a lookup chain starting with `a.__dict__['x']`, then `type(a).__dict__['x']`, and continuing through the base classes of `type(a)` *excluding metaclasses*.

There is no rationale given for this approach. However, it is sufficient to replicate common instantiation+inheritance behaviour of other languages. At the same time, it avoids arbitrarily deep lookups and the issue that `type` is a recursive metaclass.
Notably, since a metaclass is in full control of how a class behaves, it can directly define methods in the class or redefine attribute access to circumvent the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, that example was illuminating. "At the same time, ... the issue that type is a recursive metaclass." What issues might arise due to this if the lookup model included metaclasses? Sorry, I'm not too clear on what you mean by type being a recursive metaclass.

Comment: I've updated the OP with a better example of why I am defining methods on the metaclass in the first place, and why I do not want the methods to be accessible on the class.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen The base metaclass ``type`` is its own metaclass: ``type.__class__ is type``. Descending down the metaclass hierarchy for lookup would have to special case this. That's of course doable, but it adds another footnote to an already complex mechanism.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I suppose I would like to ask the core devs "given the choice between special casing this lookup vs not having the metaclass method accessible on the instance, why did you chose the latter?" For example, if someone asked me "how can I have a method accessible on a class that is not accessible on an instance", I would say "oh just define the method on the metaclass".  But I can't think of any use case where someone would want to do that.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen If someone asked _me_ "how can I have a method accessible on a class that is not accessible on an instance", I would tell them to borrow [Django's `classonlymethod` decorator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4468bcc6579402904763ffa74b4ab0e41a1cd316/django/utils/decorators.py#L6-L12) ;)

Comment: @AKX But what is the point of `classonlymethod` ? If you didn't use this decorator, a user could still call it from an instance, and it would fail, right?. I suppose this would give a pretty error message instead of the default. Additionally, the method is still visible in Pycharm's code completion (which is also True when using a metaclass). It would be great if there was a way to completely hide it, even from Pycharm's code completion.

Comment: In Django, `classonlymethod` is used for e.g. class-based views' `.as_view()`, which turn the class-based view into a view function (which instantiates the class internally); it's a smell of a bug to call it on an instance of the view class. But "how do I hide a class(only) method from the code completion engine of PyCharm [or any other IDE]?" is a different question.

Comment: @AKX Why not just define it as a classmethod ?